# Use group and row in single term

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a single column tibble

```
a
0
1
2
3
4
```

where the first three and last two rows are grouped. I would like a tidyverse expression to add two columns with the *remaining* elements of the group. Thus, I would like

```
a  b  c
0  1  2
1  0  2
2  0  1
3  4  NA
4  3  NA
```

Currently, I use something like this

```
df %>% mutate(b = a[1], c = a[2])
```

Sadly, this counts the current row as well. How can I exclude the element of the current row?

Answer (score 2):

first we generate the data frame with a defined grouping:

```
df = data.frame(a=0:4,grp=rep(1:2,c(3,2)))

  a grp
1 0   1
2 1   1
3 2   1
4 3   2
5 4   2
```

Then we group by the group and use a `map()` with `setdiff` to get the other elements. Next we explode this and then pivot wide again. There might be some easier way but this is what I can come up with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
mutate(other = map(a,~setdiff(a,.x))) %>% 
unnest(other) %>% 
group_by(a,grp) %>% 
mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols=a,names_from=id,values_from=other)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a   `1`   `2`
  <int> <int> <int>
1     0     1     2
2     1     0     2
3     2     0     1
4     3     4    NA
5     4     3    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We begin by creating our dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:2, 3:2), a = 0:4) %>% group_by(group)
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
  group     a
  <int> <int>
1     1     0
2     1     1
3     1     2
4     2     3
5     2     4
```

Now, we can make use of `combn` to access the desired elements. If the order of the remaining elements in the extra columns doesn't matter this is as simple as

```
df %>% mutate(b = unlist(combn(rev(a), n() - 1, simplify = FALSE, `[`, 1)),
              c = unlist(combn(rev(a), n() - 1, simplify = FALSE, `[`, 2)))
```

Otherwise, we have to put in a little more work to reorder the elements correctly (as in your question)

```
df %>% mutate(b = unlist(combn(rev(a), n() - 1, simplify = FALSE, function(x) {rev(x)[1]})),
              c = unlist(combn(rev(a), n() - 1, simplify = FALSE, function(x) {rev(x)[2]})))
```